# Excel (Google Spreadsheet): get values between two dates

Tags: excel-formula

I have seen lots of questions regarding this, on here and on other websites. However even with all that I have read I cannot accomplish what I want.

I have an Excel document with in cell A2 a starting date and in B2 an end date.

In A5:C11 I have a table with data. In cells A5:A11 I have dates, in B5:C11 I have the data. Now I want to display the data from B and C if they fall between the dates given in cells A2 and B2. I want to do so via a formula. I have tried many formulas with index, match, vlookup, small , sumproduct, if(s) and so on. Maybe any of you can help me?

```
Start date  End date    
29-12-2017  29-12-2017  

Date       Users    Pageviews
04-01-2018  350         400
03-01-2018  300         350
02-01-2018  250         300
01-01-2018  200         250
31-12-2017  150         200
30-12-2017  100         150
29-12-2017  50          100
```

In this case I want the output to be, preferably in 3 cells:

```
29-12-2017  50  100
```

Comment: please mock up some data and also how you want the output to look.  Put that in the original post using [edit].  There are many ways to attack this but they all depend on how you want the end result to look.

Comment: And if there are more than one you want it to display a new line?

Comment: This is what Advanced Filter is for.

Comment: Yes if it is more than one I would like it on a new line. I think I cannot use Advanced Filters since I am creating a dashboard, in which users can change the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Make another table in F5:G11 with this formula in F5 and copy over:

```
=IF(AND($A5>=$A$2,$A5<=$B$2),B5,"")
```

Then in H5:I11 use this formula to remove the blank rows (adapted from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/603118-remove-blanks-column-formula.html)):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(F$5:F$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(F$5:F$11)-ROW(F$5)+1)/(F$5:F$11<>""),ROWS(G$5:G5))),"")
```

The result:
[image]

Parameter to change in green, your data in blue, intermediate formulae in grey (hide these columns?) and the final result in orange.

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of dates use:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$5:$A$11/(($A$5:$A$11>=$A$2)*($A$5:$A$11<=$B$2)),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Then once we have the dates it is a simple Vlookup for the other two:

```
=IF(F5<>"",VLOOKUP($F5,$A$4:$C$11,COLUMN(B:B),FALSE),"")
```

Put the First in F5 and copy down.

Put the Second in G5 and copy over one column and down.

[image]